# AuthenticationBuilder does not contain a definition for AddAzureAd

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

Im following a tutorial from [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authentication-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core-2-0-using-azure-active-director/) and trying to enable OpenId Connect using Azure Ad and here's the code that I am trying to add to the Startup.cs file.

```
    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
        .AddCookie();
```

But it has red underline for `AddAzureAd` and shows this error message:

> 'AuthenticationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddAzureAd'
>   and no accessible extension method 'AddAzureAd' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'AuthenticationBuilder' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Steps I have tried:

1. Clean and rebuild the solution
2. restart visual studio

But it doesnt fix the issue. Anyone knows what's the other reason that causes this?

Comment: It looks like you need to add a reference to [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI/). Additionally, it seems to be [`AddAzureAD`](https://github.com/aspnet/AADIntegration/blob/release/2.2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI/AzureADAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs#L79) rather than `AddAzureAd`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin thanks for your reply but it still doesnt work.. :(

Comment: With both adding a reference to the package *and* changing the `d` to a `D`?

Comment: @KirkLarkin yes, it worked... i can't believe I was stuck for 2 hours just because of this... thank you very much!!!

Comment: @KirkLarkin, you could post your suggestion as the answer.

Answer (score 11):

I had the exact same loss of time with something as stupid as not adding the reference.
The answer to this question would be along the lines of:

```
 dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI --version 2.2.0
```

Notice that you may have added another reference related to authentication but not the one you are having the problem about.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar error but for me it was:

> CS1061    'AuthenticationBuilder' does not contain a definition for
> 'AddGoogle' and no accessible extension method 'AddGoogle' accepting a
> first argument of type 'AuthenticationBuilder' could be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Solved by installing NuGet `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google`

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 3):

I had to add a using statement to my Startup file.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
```

Comment: this unfortunately did not help for me :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to:

1. Add reference to [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI/) in *.cproj
2. Add `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` in Startup.cs
3. Use `.AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));`

Hope this help someone, cause I lost half an hour on it.

Comment: This method is now obsolete.  The recommended solution is to use Microsoft.Identity.Web.